# code gives unexpected output when working with eeprom

Tags: arduino, embedded, microcontroller, esp32, arduino-c++

I am trying to read EEPROM first and then write particular data to EEPROM. I am expecting previous data from EEPROM at first but it prints the data I am trying to write to EEPROM. But if I add a delay between the read and write everything works as expected. I am using an ESP32( Arduino framework) clocked at 240 Mhz. I am very suspicious about the clock frequency. I think this issue happens because the instruction speed of the controller is much higher than the baud rate. Am I right?

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define config_ver "pppp"

void saveconfig();

typedef struct {
  char version[10];
  char ssid[10];
  char pass[10];
  int settings;
} configuration_type;

configuration_type configuration = {config_ver,"lol","dk",50};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  EEPROM.begin(128);

  for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)EEPROM.read(i));    // "pppp" is printed instead of values already in eeprom.
  }
  Serial.println("\n");

  //delay(10000);                          // delay

  saveconfig();                           // "pppp" is about to write to epprom

  for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)EEPROM.read(i));
  }
  Serial.println("\n");

}

void loop() {

}

void saveconfig() {
  Serial.println("################Saving configuration################!!");
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(configuration); i++) {
    char data = *((char*)&configuration + i);
    EEPROM.write(i,data);
  }
  EEPROM.commit();
}
```

**Output:**

```
pppp␀␀␀␀␀␀lol␀␀␀␀␀␀␀dk␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀

################Saving configuration################!!
pppp␀␀␀␀␀␀lol␀␀␀␀␀␀␀dk␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀
```

**Output after adding delay:**

```
pppp␀␀␀␀␀␀lol␀␀␀␀␀␀␀dk␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀

################Saving configuration################!!
aaaa␀␀␀␀␀␀lol␀␀␀␀␀␀␀dk␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀2␀␀
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in the output?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie see the first four bytes of both output

Comment: "`"pppp"` _is printed instead of values already in eeprom"_ Well, that can't be. Maybe you see a left-over from a previous try. You should cycle between two configs to test what happens.

Comment: Does `EEPROM.write` and `EEPROM.commit` return anything?

Comment: What type of EEPROM, what type of microcontroller?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I have tried several times with different configs. No leftover from EEPROM.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie EEPROM.commit returns 1

Comment: @user253751 I am using ESP32 and its default EEPROM.

Comment: Don't use `char` type for binary values. It can be signed so it has great potential for bugs. Use `uint8_t` instead.

Comment: Do you have to wait for the commit to complete? The documentation should tell you. BTW, a quick glance revealed that the EEROM class is declared as deprecated; don't use it anymore.

Comment: A little more detail about EEPROM deprecation: The Sparkfun page Hookup page about the ESP32 Thing points to https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32; the EEPROM library in that repository, https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/EEPROM, reads "EEPROM is deprecated. For new applications on ESP32, use Preferences. EEPROM is provided for backwards compatibility with existing Arduino applications."